# Error on making build

Tags: substrate-node-template

I am following this
https://core.tetcoin.org/docs/en/tutorials/create-your-first-substrate-chain/setup

make build command gave me this error
no field __rip on type __darwin_arm_thread_state64

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think tetcoin.org was someone forking substrate years ago but then not doing anything with it. Any info there is likely to be way out of date.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to follow the authoritative docs instead:

- https://docs.substrate.io/install
- https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/build-local-blockchain